# Передать вектор структур по ссылке в функцию и выполнить в нём поиск

Tags: vector, rust

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема. Нужно найти число в векторе внутри структуры, которая находится внутри вектора этих структур. Такое себе объяснение. Думаю код лучше покажет что я хочу получить:

```
struct Player
{
    name: String,
    numbers: Vec<u32>,
}

fn find_winner(players: &Vec<Player>, target_number: u32) -> Option<String>
{
    for player in players
    {
        for it in player.numbers
        {
            if it == target_number
            {
                return Some(player.name);
            }
        }
    }
    None
}
```

Этот код выдаёт вот такие ошибки:

```
src\main.rs:25:13: 25:19 error: cannot move out of borrowed content
src\main.rs:25          for it in player.numbers
                                  ^~~~~~
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src\main.rs:25:3: 31:4 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src\main.rs:23:2: 32:3 note: expansion site
src\main.rs:29:17: 29:23 error: cannot move out of borrowed content
src\main.rs:29                          return Some(player.name);
                                                    ^~~~~~
```

В чём проблема и как исправить этот код? Спасибо!

```
> rustc --version
rustc 1.2.0 (082e47636 2015-08-03)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Rust, для небазовых типов, выражение `let a = b;` означает **перемещение** значения переменной `b` в переменную `a`. После **перемещения** доступ к `b` невозможен - время жизни переменной закончилось. Если на момент перемещения на переменную `b` есть активная ссылка, то возникнет ошибка.

Вот простой пример для иллюстрации:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo{
    val:u32
}

fn main() {

    let a = Foo{val:42};
    let refa = &a;
    let c = a;
    println!("{:?}",c);
}
```

---

```
<anon>:31:9: 31:10 error: cannot move out of `a` because it is borrowed
<anon>:31     let c = a;
                  ^
<anon>:30:17: 30:18 note: borrow of `a` occurs here
<anon>:30     let refa = &a;
```

Если к моменту перемещения значения время жизни `refa` закончится, то перемещение `let c = a` станет допустимым:

```
fn main() {

    let a = Foo{val:42};
    {
        let refa = &a;
    }
    let c = a;
    println!("{:?}",c);
}
```

Про **владение** в Rust: http://kgv.github.io/rust_book_ru/src/ownership.html

---

В вашем примере во втором цикле происходит перемещение значения, на которое существует активная ссылка. Одна ссылка берется при вызове функции, еще одна в первом цикле. Выход - сделать второй цикл по ссылкам, а не по значениям.

С возвращаемым значением тоже самое. Руст не позволит переместить значение пока на него есть живая ссылка. Лучше вернуть ссылку на строку (slice).

Вот рабочий код:

```
fn find_winner(players: &Vec<Player>, target_number: u32) -> Option<&str>
{
    for player in players
    {
        for it in &player.numbers
        {
            if *it == target_number
            {
                return Some(&player.name);
            }
        }
    }
    None
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно! Однако сложно разобраться во владениях в таких циклах. Особенно после C++, где по большей части и нет никаких правил владения. А что делает `#[derive(Debug)]`? Добавляет трейт для вывода через `{:?}`?